# Is there a way to know how many people already voted in the mod's election?

Tags: discussion, election

Is there a way to know how many people have already voted in the moderator elections?

I know the results are private until the election process ends, but is the same criterion applied to the number of voters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious method of knowing how many people have already voted in an election is to [count the number of recipients of "Constituent" badges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/86/constituent).

Comment: Nice! A pity it will not work for future elections!

Comment: Well, looking at the dates might help...

Comment: Oh ...  one badge is awarded for each election. I haven't read that

Answer (score 2):

It's shown on the election page:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Only moderators can see the vote stats prior to the end of the election, actually.

Comment: So we could expect something like 100 votes ... interesting

Comment: @GraceNote it would be useful to show anything only mods can see with a different background color or so. In quite a few occasions you really don't know whether you're seeing confidential information or not.

Comment: @Grace I echo Sjoerd's comment.  I hope this was not supposed to be privileged information but I'm not sure how I was supposed to know it was moderator-only visible.

Comment: It's nothing to be worried about spilling, and after all, there's no easy way to have known that it was mod-only before the election ends (all we do is change the visibility from "mod-only" to "everyone" at the end). I'll look into some thoughts for differentiation just to make it clearer.